# Using Ramda reject with Promises

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

How can Ramda.reject() be used with Promises?

`map()` can work like this

```
const data = [ {id: 1}, {id: 2} ]
const userIsAdmin = (user) => isAdmin(user) // async database call
const result = await Promise.all(R.map(userIsAdmin, data))
console.log(result) // [true, false]
```

But what I really want is to get the user ids back, but with admins rejected. I've tried the following code and other variations using `pipeP`.

```
await Promise.all(R.reject(async (d) => await userIsAdmin(d))(data))
```

How can this be done?

An alternative is to refactor `isAdmin()` to accept an array and just wait for one promise to complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I follow entirely, but can you not simply use `reject` on the results of `Promise.all`?

```
const result = await Promise.all(R.map(asyncFn, data))
console.log(result) //=> [true, false]
console.log(R.filter(R.identity, result)) //=> [true]
```

But perhaps there's some confusion.  You do want to use [`reject`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#reject) for what it's meant to do, right?  It is simply a variant of `filter` with the predicate reversed, i.e. the (curried) equivalent of `(fn, list) => R.filter(R.complement(fn), list)`.  It has nothing to do with the `reject` function supplied to the callback given in the Promise constructor.

### Update

With the updated question, I think the easiest approach is still to use `reject` on the results of the `Promise.all` call, but you will probably have to combine it with the original data.  Something like:

```
const removeAdmins = pipe(zip, reject(head), pluck(1))
removeAdmins(result, data)
```

`zip` combines the two (equal-length) lists into pairs.  Then calling `head` on the pair gives you back the boolean, so `reject(head)` filters out those that returned `true` from your `Promise.all` calls.  Then `pluck(1)` returns the second element (the original object) from each remaining pair.

Would that do what you want?

Comment: Thanks Scott, for taking a crack at my question, and for the awesome library. I've edited the question to include more context. I do want to `reject` based on Ramda's definition.

Comment: Updated the answer.  I *think* it would do what you want.